# How to get values from multidimensional array using checkbox in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.4

this is my array and back end (controller)

```
$newA = array("agents" => array("value" => array( "65" => array( "drive" => "number","cars" => "78"),"68" => array( "drive" => "num","cars" => "98"))));

$test2 = $r->myCheckbox;
```

Now I can display '65' and '68' this values I get from checkbox selected by users, but I want to display values in the 65 and 68.
please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your user checkbox return is $return and this equal 65. To get the value, just use `$newA['agents']['value'][$return];`

Comment: hi @Huy Trinh thanks .. i already tried your suggested answer but i still found an error.

Comment: hi @Huy Trinh thanks. so i did something like this @if($test2) { @foreach($newA['agents']['value'][$test2] as $keys)
  @foreach($keys as $key => $val) <p>{{$key}}</p> @endforeach@endforeach .. i've got an error saying that invalid argument foreach()

Comment: Yes, it's already return value already, it is not an array so you cannot use foreach. the key is $test2 already, too.

`@if($test2) { <p>{{$newA['agents']['value'][$test2]}} </p> }`

Comment: hi @Huy Trinh . I think its a multidimensional array or i was wrong

Answer (score -1):

```
$test2 = array_column($newA, 'value')[0];
$get_res  = array_keys($test2);
print_r($get_res);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.